# Proving contour integral equal to zero

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration

Let $G$ be the path traversed once as shown:

[image: ![](https://i.ibb.co/cTx0MJh/Image-460.png)]

Show that $\displaystyle{\int_{G}{\dfrac{1}{v^4-1} \text{d}v} = 0}$.

By partial fraction decomposition,
$\dfrac{1}{v^4 -1} = \dfrac{1}{4} \left( \dfrac{1}{v-1} - \dfrac{1}{v+1} + \dfrac{i}{v-i} - \dfrac{i}{v+i}  \right)$

The singular points $v = \pm 1, \pm i$ all lie inside the contour $G$. Thus, from this theorem (*), we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{G}{\dfrac{1}{v^4-1} \text{d}v} &= \dfrac{1}{4} \left( \int_{G}{\dfrac{1}{v-1}\text{d}v} - \int_{G}{\dfrac{1}{v+1}\text{d}v} + \int_{G}{\dfrac{i}{v-i}\text{d}v} - \int_{G}{\dfrac{i}{v+i}\text{d}v}  \right) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{4}\left( 2\pi i - 2\pi i + i\left( 2\pi i \right) - i \left( 2\pi i \right) \right) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{4} \left( 0 \right) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

(*) Theorem: Let $C$ be a simple closed contour with a positive orientation such that $v_0$ lies interior to $C$, then $\displaystyle{\int_{C} {\dfrac{dv}{(v-v_0)^n}} = 2\pi i}$ for $n =1$ and $0$ when $n \neq 1$ is an integer.

Is that proof correct? If so, could you also point out if there are still theorems I have to mention to make it more accurate?

I'm trying to solve (perhaps overthink) this with the other approach:

We see that it is analytic except at $\pm 1$ and $ \pm i$.
Also, we can apply deformation of the contour $G$ by forming a leaf-like contour and forming the respective circles $C_1, C_2, C_3,$ and $C_4$. As shown here:

[image: ![img](https://i.ibb.co/wS5dSqT/Image-485.png)]

The integration can then be evaluated as
$$ \int_{G}{\dfrac{1}{v^4-1} \text{d}v} = \int_{C_1}{\dfrac{1}{v^4-1} \text{d}v} + \int_{C_2}{\dfrac{1}{v^4-1} \text{d}v} + \int_{C_3}{\dfrac{1}{v^4-1} \text{d}v} + \int_{C_4}{\dfrac{1}{v^4-1} \text{d}v} $$

And,
$$\int_{C_n}{\dfrac{1}{v^4-1} \text{d}v} = \dfrac{1}{4} \left( \int_{C_n}{\dfrac{1}{v-1}\text{d}v} - \int_{C_n}{\dfrac{1}{v+1}\text{d}v} + \int_{C_n}{\dfrac{i}{v-i}\text{d}v} - \int_{C_n}{\dfrac{i}{v+i}\text{d}v}  \right) $$

Note that when $v_n$ lies exterior to $C_n$, then by Cauchy-Goursat theorem, $\displaystyle{\int_{C_n}{\dfrac{dv}{v-v_n}} = 0}$.

Thus, for $n = 1,$,
$$\int_{C_1}{\dfrac{1}{v^4-1} \text{d}v} = \dfrac{1}{4}(0-0 + i(2\pi i)- 0) = \dfrac{- \pi }{2} $$
for $ n = 2,$
$$\int_{C_2}{\dfrac{1}{v^4-1} \text{d}v} = \dfrac{1}{4}( 2\pi i  - 0 + 0-0) = \dfrac{ \pi i}{2}$$
for $ n = 3,$
$$\int_{C_3}{\dfrac{1}{v^4-1} \text{d}v} = \dfrac{1}{4}(0 - 0 + 0 - i (2\pi i) ) = \dfrac{\pi }{2}$$
for $ n = 4,$
$$\int_{C_4}{\dfrac{1}{v^4-1} \text{d}v} = \dfrac{1}{4}(0 -(2\pi i) + 0-0 ) = \dfrac{ - \pi i }{2}$$

Therefore, $$ \int_{G}{\dfrac{1}{v^4-1} \text{d}v} = \dfrac{- \pi }{2} + \dfrac{ \pi i}{2} + \dfrac{\pi }{2} + \dfrac{ - \pi i }{2} = 0$$

Did I just overcomplicate it? Is my first proof already enough? If any of these proofs are correct, could you also point out if there are still theorems I have to mention for them to make it more accurate?

Comment: Your first proof is enough, and indeed the second one seems an over-complication.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you! But is the second one still correct or already has some violations?

Comment: I see no issue in your second approach as well :)

Comment: Alright, thanks! :)

Answer (score 8):

The shortest proof is as follows:

Let $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{1}{z^4-1}$. Let $\displaystyle I=\int \limits _Cf(z)\,dz$.

Note that both the contour $C$ and the function $f$ are invariant under the rotation operation $z\mapsto iz$. Therefore, $I=iI$. Then $I=0$.

Comment: @automorp15m Good catch on the $-1$; I have fixed it. You may not be able to copy and paste this proof, but I’m sure you could fill in the details and make it rigorous.

Answer (score 5):

Since OP's first solution works just fine, I will provide yet another solution:

We "inflate" the contour $G$ so it becomes a CCW-oriented circle of radius $r > 1$.

[image: contour]

Then

$$ \int_{G} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^4 - 1}
= \int_{|z| = r} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^4 - 1}
\stackrel{(w=1/z)}{=} \int_{|w|=\frac{1}{r}} \frac{-\mathrm{d}w/w^2}{w^{-4} - 1}
= - \int_{|w|=\frac{1}{r}} \frac{w^2}{1 - w^4} \, \mathrm{d}w $$

In the last integral, $\frac{w^2}{1-w^4}$ has no poles inside the circle $|w| = \frac{1}{r}$ since $\frac{1}{r} < 1$. Therefore the integral evaluates as $0$ by the Cauchy's integral theorem.

*Remark.* This is an example of the  "[residue at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity)".

Comment: There are indeed a lot of ways to skin the cat and this is one of the nicest ways! :)

Comment: May I know how to draw that? I tried using GeoGebra but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @automorp15m, Glad you enjoyed it :) If you are referring to the tool I used, then it is *Mathematica*. If you are actually asking how to draw the curve $G$, then I would call it the [four-leaf rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrifolium) given by the polar equation of the form $r=a \cos(2\theta)$.

Comment: Haven't used Mathematica (just yet). Thank you!

Comment: It seems it's not free software.  I'd like to ask for permission to use use gif :)

Comment: @automorp15m, Indeed, it is quite expensive software especially without student discount. Anyway, you are free to use that image. :)

Comment: +1 for the figure!

Comment: My favorite answer to this question (+1). Just wanted to say that if we'd like to make the argument even more intuitive, we can start with the same inflation trick and then observe the integrand behaves asymptotically as $O(1 / r^4)$ as we increase the radius to infinity, hence the integral converges to zero. Since it's actually independent of $r$ for $r>1$, it has to be equal to $0$. But of course "under the hood", this is still equivalent to the residue at infinity being zero.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it easier by using the special symmetry your function and your path have: They both behave nicely under rotations of $e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$. For the path it is evident that $C_k = e^{k\cdot i\frac{\pi}{2}}C_1$, and for the function it is the same:

\begin{align}f(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}z) &= \frac{1}{(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}z-1)(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}z-i)(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}+i)(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}+1)(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}+i)} \\ &= e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{(z-e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})(z-ie^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})(z+e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})(z+ie^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})}\\ &= e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-i)(z+1)(z+i)}\\ &= e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}}f(z)
\end{align}

So with the same notation as in your own post, you can write
\begin{align}\int\limits_{C_k} f(z) dz = \int\limits_{C_1}f(e^{k\cdot i\frac{\pi}{2}}z) dz = e^{-k\cdot i\frac{\pi}{2}} \int\limits_{C_1}f(z) dz,\end{align}
so by adding up the different terms you end up with
$$\int\limits_G f(z) dz = \int\limits_{C_1}f(z) dz\cdot\sum\limits_{k=1}^4 e^{-k\cdot i\frac{\pi}{2}} = \int\limits_{C_1}f(z) dz\cdot(1+i-1-i) = 0$$

Comment: that's a nice approach there!